# upstart CentOS vs upstart Ubuntu is there any difference between them?

Tags: ubuntu, centos, upstart, startup-scripts

I'm moving some server configurations from Ubuntu Server 12.04 to CentOS 6.6. Now I'm working on `/etc/init` script that should be handled by `upstart` at both OS as far as I know. The files on both server are the same and I mean the same at content level and also at path level and permissions level, is the exactly copy from Ubuntu to CentOS. I'm having some issues with upstart at CentOS since scripts doesn't start and I can't find why (the cause). This is the output from `initctl list` at Ubuntu server:

```
# Ubuntu 12.04
root@qa:/etc/init# initctl list
// rest of processes goes here
pdoneVendorBroker start/running, process 854
repToolBroker start/running, process 3705
emailBroker start/running, process 3738
cmeBroker start/running, process 3760
messageBroker start/running, process 3727
shareEventHandler start/running, process 3686
edetailBroker start/running, process 3749
pdoneLoginProctor start/running, process 3716
```

All the processes has been started at OS boot, that's fine.

This is the output from CentOS server:

```
# CentOS 6.6
root@staging:/etc/init# initctl list
// rest of processes goes here
pdoneVendorBroker stop/waiting
repToolBroker stop/waiting
emailBroker stop/waiting
cmeBroker stop/waiting
messageBroker stop/waiting
shareEventHandler stop/waiting
edetailBroker stop/waiting
pdoneLoginProctor stop/waiting
```

None processes has been started after OS boot, and that's wrong. Why? What I'm missing here? Can any give me some advice?

At CentOS I've tried also to start the process manually by running this:

```
initctl start cmeBroker.conf
```

But I got this error:

> initctl: Unknown job: cmeBroker.conf

This is the content for the file `/ etc/init`cmbBroker.conf`:

```
description "cmeBroker"

start on runlevel [234]
stop on runlevel [0156]

respawn
exec php /usr/local/bin/cmeBroker/cmeBroker.php
post-start script
    PID=`status cmeBroker | egrep -oi '([0-9]+)$' | head -n1`
    echo $PID > /var/run/cmeBroker.pid
end script

post-stop script
    rm -f /var/run/cmeBroker.pid
end script
```

It's wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Open the messages system log `tail /var/log/messages` you will see an error log telling you the problem and the line number.
Looks like this:

```
Sep 21 16:34:28 0 init: /etc/init/uwsgi.conf:9: Unknown stanza
```